# Making a hamburger menu from a animated logo

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am learning basic HTML in high school and I am currently stuck on a hamburger menu from a animated logo.

I want the logo i have made to open a collapsed sidemenu/hamburger menu. Something along the lines of these examples:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_collapse_sidebar.asp
https://codepen.io/DeolaJ/pen/xvjbKY
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_curtain_menu.asp

If possible I would like to avoid java ( as long as the css doesnt get insane )..

Thank you in advance :)

```js
function myFunction(x) {
  x.classList.toggle("change");
}
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bar1,
.bar2,
.bar3 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  margin: 6px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.change .bar1 {
  transform: translate(0, 11px) rotate(-45deg);
}

.change .bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.change .bar3 {
  transform: translate(0, -11px) rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container" onclick="myFunction(this)">
  <div class="bar1"></div>
  <div class="bar2"></div>
  <div class="bar3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also, this is my first time posting on stack overflow (obviously).. sorry for the messed up text etc. The top function line is the only java in the program, and everything until <div class="container" etc. is the css.

Comment: I think you mean 'JavaScript' not 'Java'

Comment: @AHaworth I probably do, sorry 

Answer (score 0):

First of all it is called javascript, not java. In order to listen click on logo you must use it, css is not able to detect clicks.

Try to add onclick listener to your logo element and show menu on that event.
One of possible solutions could be:

```
<custom-logo-element onclick="showMenu"></custom-logo-element>

<div class="container">
    <div class="bar1"></div>
    <div class="bar2"></div>
    <div class="bar3"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function showMenu() {
    const element = document.querySelector('.container')
    element.classList.add('visible')
}
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.visible {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: 'css is not able to detects clicks' - true in a general sense, but if you use an input of type checkbox then i tcan detect the checked state.

Comment: @Vasyl I have tried implementing what you are saying, first the button disappeared, I have it visible again, the animation works aswell. But how do i get the menu to appear?

Comment: @vasyl Also, how do I add code to a comment? Perhaps I could show you how my code looks now.